# Custom Taxonomy WP_Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to display a custom post type that has custom taxonomy, but I am not having any luck. Nothing is showing up. I appreciate any help.

Post type = gallery

Custom Taxonomy slug = photoarea

The 'photoarea' I want to display = fourth

[image]

```
<?php 

$args = array( 
               'post_type' => 'gallery', 
               'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'photoarea',
                        'field' => 'fourth', 
                        )
                ),
               'posts_per_page' => 10,
              );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

     the_post_thumbnail();

 endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if my understanding is right, that you need to get the custom taxonomy with following code,
instead of `field` you must use `term` to get the posts in Fourth

```
<?php 

$args = array( 
               'post_type' => 'gallery', 
               'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'photoarea',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'fourth'
                        )
                ),
               'posts_per_page' => 10,
              );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

     the_post_thumbnail();

 endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Comment: you need 'field' => 'slug' and 'terms' => 'fourth' to get this work, not 'term'.

Answer (score 1):

You may use below code snippet:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=gallery&photoarea=fourth');
```

and then your while loop.

Answer (score -3):

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'gallery','posts_per_page'=>'-1','tax_query' => array(array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'photoarea',
                                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                                        'terms'    => $your_term_id,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            );
```